# How to reload an embedded tweet button

Tags: javascript, twitter, embed

On website [foradacopa.com](http://www.foradacopa.com) and most websites I develop, we load partial page content into the current DOM to create a "one page" website experience. When these partial pages have embedded tweet buttons, the first page loaded will display the tweet button properly whereas subsequent pages loaded will not. This is because the Twitter code only does it's magic once, when the code is loaded initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this, you need to manually call a method that will do the magic to turn your static a tag into the iframe embedded button.

```
twttr.widgets.load()
```

I found this answer at https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5642 from @kurrik Arne Roomann-Kurrik.